# String search that ignores "a", "the", etc. with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for something like:

```
if(magicSearch("hot pizza","We sell pizza that is really hot") {//Found!}
```

I only want a "true" if both words appear (any order) and I want it to ignore things like "a", "and", "the", etc., in the text to be searched for.

(I'm sure there is better terminology to explain what I'm looking for)

I've seen various DB engines support this type of text search (e.g. Mongodb) but I need a simply JavaScript way of testing strings.  I can build it, but it feels like something that must already be out there somewhere.

Greg

Comment: Not sure if there's already something out there, but you can split the first string on the whitespace, use the regex `test` method on each one, and return false if any fail, and true when all pass. As for eliminating stop words like "a", "the", etc., I think you'll need to create an array of stop words to strip, and pull those out before you test for each of the words.

Comment: You want to build heuristic search module with **stop words** list.

Comment: As someone else said in their answer, `indexOf` is simpler and faster than the regex `test` method. Sorry for the bad advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `indexOf` function in a simple loop.

```
//Use this if you don't need to find exact matches of words
function magicSearch(needles, haystack) {
    var searchTerms = (needles instanceof Array) ? needles : [needles];
    for(var i = 0; i < searchTerms.length; i++) {
        if(haystack.indexOf(searchTerms[i]) === -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//Use this if you want to find exact matches of words
function magicSearch2(needles, haystack) {
    var searchTerms = (needles instanceof Array) ? needles : [needles],
        haystackArray = haystack.split(' '),
        index, 
        found = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < haystackArray.length; i++) {
        index = searchTerms.indexOf(haystackArray[i]);
        if(index !== -1) {
            delete searchTerms[i];
            found++;
            if(found = searchTerms.length) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
if(magicSearch(["hot", "pizza"],"We sell pizza that is really hot") {
    console.log("FOUND");
}
if(magicSearch2(["hot", "pizza"],"We sell pizza that is really hot")) {     
    console.log("FOUND");
}
```

Comment: note: `(needles instanceof Array)` won't work correctly if you are sharing objects across iFrame or window boundaries, since then they'll be instances of the other document's `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **[underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)**, you can have some relative simple implementation

```
var stopwords_set = ["a", "and", "the" ];
var magicSearch = function (keywords, str) {
    var content_set = {};
    var keywords_set = {};

    _.each(keywords.split(' '), function(item){
        keywords_set[item.toLowerCase()] = 1;
    });

    _.each(str.split(' '), function(item){
        content_set[item.toLowerCase()] = 1;
    });

    //convert input to 2 sets excluding stop words
    content_set = _.without(_.keys(content_set), stopwords_set);
    keywords_set = _.without(_.keys(keywords_set), stopwords_set);

    //check the intersecion
    var value = _.intersection(content_set, keywords_set).length == keywords_set.length
    return value;
}

magicSearch("hot pizza","We sell pizza that is really hot");
```